# InvalidStateException while trying to enter data into DB

Tags: java, jpa, openjpa

I have a method that return the entity manager for particular DB.Now when i use the method for the first time to get entity manager everything works fine.I can save data into any tables A,B,C using entity manager.Now say i get a exception while saving in table B

Now when I try to perform any operation on DB after geting exception above, the next time  i  try to run same code it fails when updating in table A itself.I can see folloing eception

```
                                 <openjpa-1.2.2-SNAPSHOT-r422266:778978M-OPENJPA-975 nonfatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.InvalidStateException: The factory has been closed.  The stack trace at which the factory was closed is available if Runtime=TRACE logging is enabled.
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.AbstractBrokerFactory.assertOpen(AbstractBrokerFactory.java:673)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.AbstractBrokerFactory.newBroker(AbstractBrokerFactory.java:182)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingBrokerFactory.newBroker(DelegatingBrokerFactory.java:142)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:192)
    at ..
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhere in your code you (or a framework) close your `EntityManagerFactory`. Make sure you didn't call `close()` on it.

Comment: can entity manager factory closed by container automatically?Do i need to do some setting in web.xml or persistene.xml?

Comment: @akshay The life cycle of the entity manager and the associated persistence context is managed automatically by the container. You don't need to open or close anything.