# What is closing the EntityManagerFactory in Worklight?

Tags: jquery-mobile, openjpa, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm experimenting with form based authentication on the IBM Worklight platform, and I'm currently following a tutorial located [here](http://wpcertification.blogspot.co.uk/2012/06/how-to-enable-authentication-in.html).

I have some wierd behaviour whereby the first time I attempt a login it will just reload the login page, but if I try a second time with the exact same details, it works. This behaviour is consistent and I'm able to reproduce it every time.

Looking closer at the JS console, I can see this being printed :

```
openjpa-1.2.2-r422266:898935 nonfatal user error&amp;gt; org.apache.openjpa.persistence.InvalidStateException: The factory has been closed.  The stack trace at which the factory was closed is available if Runtime=TRACE logging is enabled.
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.AbstractBrokerFactory.assertOpen(AbstractBrokerFactory.java:673)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.AbstractBrokerFactory.newBroker(AbstractBrokerFactory.java:182)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingBrokerFactory.newBroker(DelegatingBrokerFactory.java:142)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:192)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:145)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:56)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor70.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean$ManagedEntityManagerFactoryInvocationHandler.invoke(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:434)
    at $Proxy36.createEntityManager(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.doGetTransactionalEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:195)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.getTransactionalEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:142)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryAccessor.getTransactionalEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryAccessor.java:129)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTemplate.execute(JpaTemplate.java:174)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTemplate.executeFind(JpaTemplate.java:151)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTemplate.findByNamedQuery(JpaTemplate.java:343)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationDAO.getAssociatedIdentities(AuthenticationDAO.java:93)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationContext$1.run(AuthenticationContext.java:513)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationContext$1.run(AuthenticationContext.java:492)
    at com.worklight.core.util.RssBrokerUtils.doInTransaction(RssBrokerUtils.java:123)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationContext.saveAuthenticationResult(AuthenticationContext.java:492)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationContext.processRequest(AuthenticationContext.java:244)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.FilterRegistration.doFilter(FilterRegistration.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:35)
    at com.worklight.gadgets.serving.filters.AuthenticityFilter.doFilter(AuthenticityFilter.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.FilterRegistration.doFilter(FilterRegistration.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:35)
    at com.worklight.gadgets.serving.filters.InstanceAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(InstanceAuthenticationFilter.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.FilterRegistration.doFilter(FilterRegistration.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty.internal.HttpServerManager$InternalHttpServiceServlet.service(HttpServerManager.java:317)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:390)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:939)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:756)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

Searching for that stacktrace reveals a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4563474/invalidstateexception-while-trying-to-enter-data-into-db) SO, whereby it has been suggested that something is calling `close()` on the `EntityManagerFactory`. I'm not sure where/why this is happening, since all of this would be managed under Worklight.

This is the JS I have for the authentication process, under `js/auth.js`

```js
var Authenticator = function() {
    var LOGIN_PAGE_SECURITY_INDICATOR = 'j_security_check';
    var USERNAME_INPUT_ID = '#usernameInputField';
    var PASSWORD_INPUT_ID = '#passwordInputField';
    var LOGIN_BUTTON_ID = '#loginButton';
    function onFormSubmit() {
        WL.Logger.debug("Entering auth.js.onFormSubmit()");
        var reqURL = './' + LOGIN_PAGE_SECURITY_INDICATOR;
        var params = {
            j_username : $(USERNAME_INPUT_ID).val(),
            j_password : $(PASSWORD_INPUT_ID).val()
        };
        onSubmitCallback(reqURL, {
            parameters : params
        });
    }
    return {
        init : function() {
            WL.Logger.debug("Inside auth.js.init");
            $(LOGIN_BUTTON_ID).bind('click', onFormSubmit);
        },
        isLoginFormResponse : function(response) {
            WL.Logger.debug("Inside auth.js.isLoginFormResponse " + response.responseText);
            if (!response || response.responseText == null) {
                WL.Logger.debug("Entering auth.js.isLoginFormResponse (), return false");
                return false;
            }
            var indicatorIdx = response.responseText.search(LOGIN_PAGE_SECURITY_INDICATOR);
            WL.Logger.debug("Entering auth.js.isLoginFormResponse (), return " + (indicatorIdx >= 0));
            return (indicatorIdx >= 0);
        },
        onBeforeLogin : function(response, username, onSubmit, onCancel) {
            WL.Logger.debug("Inside auth.js.onBeforeLogin");
            onSubmitCallback = onSubmit;
            onCancelCallback = onCancel;
            if (typeof (username) != 'undefined' && username != null) {
                $(USERNAME_INPUT_ID).val(username);
            } else {
                $(USERNAME_INPUT_ID).val('');
            }
            $(PASSWORD_INPUT_ID).val('');
        },
        onShowLogin : function() {
            WL.Logger.debug("Inside auth.js.onShowLogin");
            $.mobile.changePage("#loginPage");
        },
        onHideLogin : function() {
            WL.Logger.debug("Inside auth.js.onHideLogin");
            $.mobile.changePage("#page3");

        }
    };
}();
```

Like I mentioned, the login fails on the first time, it just reloads the login form and I can see the above stack trace in the JS console, but the second time it works fine. I'm wondering if something is not being initialised correctly on the first attempt, but is fine for the second. Can anyone suggest what is wrong?

These are the page elements that I'm using :

```html
<div data-role="page" id="page3">
            <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
              <h3>Autenticated Page - Page3</h3>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content">
              <h3>You are logged in -Page3</h3>
              <a href="#page1">Go to page1</a>
            </div>
            <div data-theme="a" data-role="footer">
              <input type="button" value="Logout" 
              onclick="WL.Client.logout('SampleAppRealm', {onSuccess:  WL.Client.reloadApp});" />
            </div>
          </div>

          <div data-role="page" id="loginPage">
            <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
              <h3>Hello JQuery Mobile</h3>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content">
              <div id="loginForm">
                Username:<br/>
                <input type="text" id="usernameInputField" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" /><br />
                Password:<br/>
                <input type="password" id="passwordInputField" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off"/><br/>    
                <input type="button" id="loginButton" value="Login" />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div data-theme="a" data-role="footer">
              <h3>Copyright stuff</h3>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: What version of Worklight are you using?
Do you use login on demand or on startup?

Comment: It seems this is done on Worklight pre-5.0.0.3, as the implemented authentication does not match that of the authentication framework introduced in 5.0.0.3 (see: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27036063).

Have you tried your application with the most recent version of Worklight, v5.0.5.1?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the EntityManagerFactory bit, but it doesn't sound related.

From reading the scenario in the question, it sounds like a login attempt is taking place prior to having the app successfully connect to the Worklight Server. Make sure your application first connects connects to the Worklight Server, and only after doing so, the login will take place.

Use either `connectOnStartup:true` in `initOptions.js` or utilize [WL.Client.Connect](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/apiref/r_wl_client_connect.html) as soon as the app has finished loading.

Also, [read these IBM Worklight Getting Started training modules](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html#security).